# HTML link to div not snapping on padding bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a link

```
<li><a href="#download">Download</a>
</li>
```

which links to

```
<div class="jumbotron second" id="download">
  <div class="container">

    <p>
         eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud

    </p>
```

I am using bootstrap jumbotron on the div.

My Problem is that when I click on the link I do not get to the top of the Jumbotron but directly to the text. This is because of the padding from the text which seems to be ignored.

I tried it on another page without bootstrap and there it links to the top of the div, not directly to the text.

How can I make the link go to the top of the Jumbotron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, I like to put the anchor on another element, above the first.

```
<span id='download'>&nbsp;</span>
<div class="jumbotron second">
  <div class="container">
```

edit:

you could just add a space to it. I like how generic/non-semantic this is because it's done to affect behavior, and thus shouldn't have semantic meaning.

**edit:** in that case:

isn't the better solution to add the padding to your body?

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Somehow this only works if I put some content into the span. Some css-attribute I need to give to the Span?

Comment: I actually removed the padding from the top of the body completely. Because it is a one-pager and everything is a jumbotron with padding-top now. But thanks alot. You helped me to find the problem in my particular case :)

Comment: sweet. glad you got it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my particular problem by adding an extra 50px of padding-top to the jumbotron.

I have the standard bootstrap navbar which is 50px high and was lying perfeclty over the 48 px padding of the jumbotron which made it seem like the link is snapping on the text.

I forgot to say that I am using the fixed navbar. Sorry for that.

Comment: check my edit. It may prevent you from running into the problem again on this same page.